# findBy - updating multiple records in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have multiple answer results for one question that I get. I want to update my number field as in example for every answer of that question.

Problem is it always updates one. In works fine with findOneBy but, still it updates just one answer.

I tried with foreach but I think my syntax is wrong because "answer" is not recognized anywhere.

```
$answers = $this->getAnswerRepository()->findBy(['question' => $question]);

        foreach ($answers as $answer) {
            $answer = new Answer();
            $this->em->persist($answer);

        }


    $answer->setNumbers($answer->getNumbers() +1);

    $this->em->flush();

    return $answer;
```

Comment: Create a repository method and update.

Comment: Checking `if(!$answers) {` and then use `foreach ($answers as...` don't make sense...

Comment: Also in `Answer` constructor you can set `number` property to `1` as initial value.

Comment: Also it's unclear why you overwrite `$answer` with new instance of `Answer`?

Comment: Should I use instanceof ? @u_mulder

Comment: Why do you need instance of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$answers = $this->getAnswerRepository()->findBy(['question' => $question]);
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    $answer->setNumbers($answer->getNumbers() +1);
}
$this->em->flush();
```

But a better solution is using a separate method in `AnswerRepository` something like:

```
function updateCounts($question) 
{
    $queryBuilder
        ->update('answers', 'a')
        ->set('a.number', 'a.number + 1')
        ->where('a.question', '?')
        ->setParameter($question)
    ;
}
```

And call something like:

```
$this->getAnswerRepository()->updateCounts($question);
```

Comment: I would add `return $answers;` in the end

Comment: `return` is not related to problem

Comment: I made a reckless mistake. Now it works. Thanks a lot! @u_mulder

Comment: Absolutely right  - but that can hint OP that the var `$answer` is useless out of loop scope and he should return the `$answers` var

Comment: @develops mark answer as __accepted__ if it helps. Do the same with other your questions if they have answers.